# In Java, how can I convert an InputStream into a byte array (byte[])?

Tags: java, type-conversion, inputstream

My background is .net, I'm fairly new to Java.  I'm doing some work for our company's java team and the architect needs me to implement a method that takes an InputStream (java.io) object.  In order to fulfill the method's purpose I need to convert that into a byte array.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Be aware that this may be memory hogging.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The simplest way is to create a new `ByteArrayOutputStream`, copy the bytes to that, and then call `toByteArray`:

```
public static byte[] readFully(InputStream input) throws IOException
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int bytesRead;
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1)
    {
        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    return output.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: Make sure you flush the outputstream before returning.

Comment: @quikchange: There's no need when you're using a ByteArrayOutputStream - where would it buffer to?

Answer (score 9):

A simple way would be to use `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray( inputStream )`, see [apache commons io](http://commons.apache.org/io/).