# Convert InputStream(Image) to ByteArrayInputStream

Tags: java, image, inputstream

Not sure about how I am supposed to do this. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Since ByteArrayInputStream are construct from byte[] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163644/in-java-how-can-i-convert-an-inputstream-into-a-byte-array-byte http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264709/convert-inputstream-to-byte-in-java

Comment: What exactly are you doing with images where you wouldn't be using the `javax.imageio` classes?

Comment: Uploading to Amazon S3... The Java library I'm using required ByteArrayInputStream for all non-string based data

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Read from input stream and write to a [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#ByteArrayOutputStream%28int%29), then call its `toByteArray()` to obtain the byte array.

Create a [ByteArrayInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) around the byte array to read from it.

Here's a quick test:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test {


       public static void main(String[] arg) throws Throwable {
          File f = new File(arg[0]);
          InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);

          byte[] buff = new byte[8000];

          int bytesRead = 0;

          ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

          while((bytesRead = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
             bao.write(buff, 0, bytesRead);
          }

          byte[] data = bao.toByteArray();

          ByteArrayInputStream bin = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
          System.out.println(bin.available());
       }
}
```

Comment: I was almost there! Thanks for the example tho. A true master of IO!

Comment: large buffer size though

Answer (score 19):

You can use org.apache.commons.io.**IOUtils#toByteArray**(java.io.InputStream)

```
InputStream is = getMyInputStream();
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(IOUtils.toByteArray(is));
```

Comment: why `IOUtils.toByteArray(is)` instead of  `is.readAllBytes()` ?

Comment: @mathiasfk no specific reason, just force of habit (never tried the other)

Comment: EDIT: because it is available only since Java 9, and I was using 7 / 8  (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/when-to-use-the-readallbytes-method-of-inputstream-in-java-9 )

Answer (score 4):

Or first convert it to a byte array, then to a bytearrayinputstream.

```
File f = new File(arg[0]);
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);
// convert the inpustream to a byte array
byte[] buf = null;
try {
    buf = new byte[in.available()];
    while (in.read(buf) != -1) {
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Got exception while is -> bytearr conversion: " + e);
}
// now convert it to a bytearrayinputstream
ByteArrayInputStream bin = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Kotlin and `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils` `v2` is simple like that:

```
IOUtils.toByteArray(is).inputStream()
```

I guess is the same way in Java too.