# how to attach multiple files to email using scala and liftweb

Tags: scala, lift

I'm trying to attach multiple files I'm writing `REST` Service for that but the files are not loading
my code look like below:-

HTML:-

```
<form action="DemoEmailAttachment" method="post">
    To: <input type="text" name="to"><br>
    Subject: <input type="text" name="subject"><br>
    Body:<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="body"></textarea><br>
    AttachFiles:<input type="file" name="fileupload" multiple="multiple"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">       
</form>
```

SCALA:-

```
object demoAttachment {

 def sendAtchMail(request: Req) = {

val obj = request._params
println(obj)
LiftRules.handleMimeFile = OnDiskFileParamHolder.apply
val fileupload = request.uploadedFiles
println(fileupload)

val to = (obj.get("to").get)(0).split(",")
val subject = obj.get("subject").get
val body = obj.get("body").get

case class CSVFile(bytes: Array[Byte],filename:String,mime:String )
var data = Array[Byte]()
println(data.length)

val ls =  fileupload.map(c => c match {
  case ff:OnDiskFileParamHolder => {  ff.fileStream.read(data)

    val attach =  CSVFile(data,ff.fileName,ff.mimeType)
    val msg =  XHTMLPlusImages(<p>Please research the enclosed.               </p>,PlusImageHolder(attach.filename, attach.mime, attach.bytes))
    Mailer.sendMail(
      From("536@gmail.com"),
      Subject(subject(0)),
      To(to(0)),

      msg
    )
  }
  case _ => "there are no files"
} )
"success"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [XHTMLPlusImages](http://liftweb.net/api/25/api/#net.liftweb.util.Mailer$XHTMLPlusImages) constructor takes a vararg for the attachment parameter. So, just pass in multiple attachments, like this:

```
XHTMLPlusImages(NodeSeq, attach1, attach2, attach3, ...)
```

Also, you should verify that `data` actually contains what you are looking send. Unless I am mistaken, the way you are reading the data from the stream will only read in however many bytes your `Array[Byte]` can hold, which is probably 0. There is a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163644/in-java-how-can-i-convert-an-inputstream-into-a-byte-array-byte) that discusses reading from the `InputStream` to a `ByteArray`.