# String max size for 722MB xml file

Tags: java, xml

I have a `ByteArrayOutputStream` which holds a byte representation of an XML with 750MB size.

I need to convert it to String.

I wrote:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream xmlArchive = ...
String xmlAsString = xmlArchive.toString(UTF8);
```

However although I am using 4GB of heap size I get java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

What is wrong? How can I know which heap size to use? I am using JDK64 bit

**UPDATE**

I need it as String in order to remove all the characters before `"<?xml"`

Currently my code is:

```
String xmlAsString = xmlArchive.toString(UTF8);
int xmlBegin = xmlAsString.indexOf("<?xml");
if (xmlBegin >0){
        return xmlAsString.substring(xmlBegin);
}
return xmlAsString;
```

I then convert it again to byte array.

**UPDATED 2**
The ByteArrayOutputStream is written like this:

```
HttpMethod method ..
InputStream response = method.getResponseBodyAsStream();
byte[] buf = new byte[5000];
while ( (len=response.read(buf)) != -1) {
    output.write(buf, 0, len);
}
```

`len` is from the header of the response `Content-Length`

Comment: Do you really need it as a string in memory? What are you going to do with it afterwards? Bear in mind that `ByteArrayOutputStream.toString()` always uses the platform-default encoding, which probably isn't a good idea.

Comment: "Bear in mind that ByteArrayOutputStream.toString() always uses the platform-default encoding, which probably isn't a good idea" doesn't sending as variable as UTF-8 influences it? I will update my question

Comment: xmlArchive.toString(UTF8);

Comment: A String character requires 2 bytes. -- Apart from that: what's the idea of having this String?

Comment: Right. Assuming the bytes are genuinely a UTF-8 representation, that's better... but I would still try to avoid doing this anyway. What are you really trying to achieve? Having a 1.5GB char array in memory really isn't going to scale well...

Comment: @laune I updated my question. I get the ByteArrayOutpuStream and need to remove the bytes until <?xml

Comment: xmlArchive: 0.7 GB + xmlAsString 1.4 GB = 2.2 GB. Did you try `new ByteArrayOutputStream(758_000_000)`? By the way ByteBuffer, CharSequence might be interesting too.

Comment: @JoopEggen I need to convert it to string to remove the beginning of the characters until <?xml how would the suggested solution help?

Comment: You might use writeTo( x ) where x is a PipedOutputStream connected to a PipedInputStream (in another thread) which will then, hopefully, write the stuff after <?xml to a file. -- But why wasn't the garbage avoided when writing to that ByteArrayOutputStream???

Comment: @laune do you suggest writing it to a file and then reading it from it?

Comment: We need to see how the `ByteArrayOutputStream` is being written to.

Comment: No, not in order to eleiminate the garbage preceding "<?xml...". See javadoc on java.io.Piped*Stream.

Comment: @Dejel And what are you doing finally with this data?

Comment: Piped I/O of @laune is fine, and a nice mental excercise. Extending an InputStream wrapping the original InputStream is possible too. It reads till `<?xml` and on subsequent reads first outputs `<` etc. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23886788/removing-ascii-characters-in-a-string-with-encoding/23890976#23890976

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(response, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());

// skip to "<?xml"
scanner.skip(".*?(?=<\\?xml)");

// process rest of stream
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    // Do something with line
}
scanner.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Jamie Cockburn's answer:

To fill in his while loop to match your expected behaviour:

```
byte[] buf = line.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
output.write(buf, 0, buf.length);
```

Comment: Totally, but I'm still not convinced that the OP really *wants* to be saving the lot to a buffer...

Comment: Thanks I need it be written to the buffer for later processing I am checking now the code and update

Comment: I would accept your answer as well, but can't accept 2. Thanks for your help though! I voted it up